# Why can't I use org.json.JSONObject to replace com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I use websphere v9beta (supporting JAX-RS 2.0) to implement restful. I have the following code.

```
@GET
@Path("/getJson1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject getJSON1() {
    String input = "This is input";
    String output = "This is output";
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("input", input);
    outputJsonObj.put("output", output);
    return outputJsonObj;
}
```

If I use "import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject", it runs normally. But if I use "import org.json.JSONObject" to implement Json. I got the following error.

```
[ERROR] Problem with writing the data, class org.json.JSONObject, ContentType: application/json
[WARNING] Interceptor for HelloResource1 has thrown exception, unwinding now
No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

I think org.json is more general, but why can't I relace com.ibm.json on websphere?

Comment: Why can't I use a sledgehammer instead of a frying pan, geez? :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are two completely different classes from different libraries. You should read the relevant documentation and make sure you're using the correct libraries for the task you want to accomplish.

Comment: com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject is embedded in WebSphere, so I can use it directly. But I want make the program more general. So I want to use org.json. I don't think they are different classes, because they should support Java EE specification. So I think they are replaced by each other.